# obj = json.dumps(j) UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

My goal is to pass the data coming in as a JSON to my script, but I am getting this error that saying "j" referenced before assignment. I saw many similar errors like this but no one could help me

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'j' referenced before assignment

Here is the code I've used:

```
def get_payload(table,item):
    message={}
    message_list = []
    message_object = {}
    if table=='TABLE_01':
        message_object['type'] = "Some.Type1"
        payload = {
            "column1": item['COLUMN1'],
            "column2": item['COLUMN2']
        }
    elif table=='TABLE_02':
        j = [
            {
                "type": "Some.Type2",
                "payload": {
                  "column1": item['COLUMN1'],
                  "column2": item['COLUMN2']
                  }
              },
            {
             "type": "Some.Type2",
                "payload": {
                  "column1": item['COLUMN1'],
                  "column2": item['COLUMN2']
                  }
            }
         ]

    obj = json.dumps(j)
    payload = json.loads(obj)

    print(type(payload))

    if type(payload) == list:
        payload2 = []
        for i in range(len(payload)):
            payload2 = [d for d in payload if "" not in d.values()]
        payload = payload2
    else:
        payload = {k:v for (k,v) in payload.items() if v != ""}
    print(payload)

    message_object['payload'] = payload
    message_list.append(message_object)
    message['messages'] = message_list
    return message
```

Comment: This is happening because you've declared variable 'j' in elif part, but using it outside. Instead declare it outside in the function before if-else statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is self explanatory.
You are trying to use `obj = json.dumps(j)`, but the variable `j` is only declared in your `elif` clause.

As such, if your code goes into the first `if` clause, the variable `j` is never declared, and so you are referencing it before assignment.

Indenting the following lines so that they are part of the `elif` clause will solve the problem.

```py
obj = json.dumps(j)
payload = json.loads(obj)
```

Final code:

```py
import json


def get_payload(table, item):
    message = {}
    message_list = []
    message_object = {}
    if table == 'TABLE_01':
        message_object['type'] = "Some.Type1"
        payload = {
            "column1": item['COLUMN1'],
            "column2": item['COLUMN2']
        }
    elif table == 'TABLE_02':
        j = [
            {
                "type": "Some.Type2",
                "payload": {
                    "column1": item['COLUMN1'],
                    "column2": item['COLUMN2']
                  }
              },
            {
                "type": "Some.Type2",
                "payload": {
                    "column1": item['COLUMN1'],
                    "column2": item['COLUMN2']
                  }
            }
         ]

        obj = json.dumps(j)
        payload = json.loads(obj)

    print(type(payload))

    if type(payload) == list:
        payload2 = []
        for i in range(len(payload)):
            payload2 = [d for d in payload if "" not in d.values()]
        payload = payload2
    else:
        payload = {k: v for (k, v) in payload.items() if v != ""}
    print(payload)

    message_object['payload'] = payload
    message_list.append(message_object)
    message['messages'] = message_list
    return message
```